Can anyone please help me understand what happend to my 1 solona token
In January I got a airdrop and claimed the tokens then made a swap. I immediately wanted to send the solona to my coinbase account. I often like to do test transactions so I first sent 0.01 solona as a test transaction. Due to me not being super familiar with solona and the wrappedsol. I swapped my airdrop using phantom wallet then realized I had got back wrapped sol so I switched to my coinbase wallet which showed my sol balance as 0.99 sol. Which it was wrapped sol so I wanted to send the 0.01 to make sure I received it on coinbase without a problem. Which I did. It was around a hour later that I checked and seen I received the 0.01 sol so I opened coinbase wallet to send the rest. However my balance was 0 and somehow the tokens got sent out of my wallet but I did not approve or make any other transactions. I was actually eating after sending the 0.01 test transaction and didn't even have my phone. So I have no idea how the transaction even happened. No other tokens or nfts was stolen or anything to think the wallet is compromised. I am hoping someone can look at the transaction or maybe transactions near this one to see if I interacted with some scam at some point which caused it. I am not new to crypto or using blockchains just not as familiar with solona as others. Not much I have not seen or do not understand on evm chains in order to figure something like this out on my own by looking onchain at my transactions. So this has really baffled me and I would just like to learn what happens so that I understand and can not let it happen again. I avoid solona all together at this point since I don't understand. Here is the transaction where I sent the other 0.99 sol to wherever or somehow my wallet initiated the transaction or the wallet is compromised somehow. I just would think other items would have got stolen if that was the case. I would greatly appreciate any help or information. I hope it is ok to ask this question here. I am just ubable to find anywhere to ask or get helo so far. I seen another question somone asked about their sol wallet making transactions on it'd own. Which I liked the answer to it because it was from them actually receiving nft airdrops not making transactions. It led me here to ask this question. I am wondering if I interacted with some scam and approved my wallet to spend tokens or something. If its even possible to that like allowing another wallet to initiate transactions for me somehow. Which is all I can think is possible other than my wallet compromised and someone had my keys and initiated the transaction that way..
Thanks
2ZB63QMhcWJiC1MmW1JcS4osPuyxXCdid6U5S8c7BS1fnnYji8BsmFgCUYS2NCK9YwuQQSxHWJQXxz7kntuy9vvC
